# Using Linq to filter out specific element content

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I'm trying to use LINQ in a .Net application to filter out personal data from the XML I save to a database.

Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
         <Details>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <objectList>
               <object>
                  <Key>Account</Key>
                  <Value>12345</Value>
               </object>
               <object>
                  <Key>Password</Key>
                  <Value>abcd</Value>
               </object>
            </objectList>
         </Details>
</Body>
```

What I have working:

```
var xmlFile = File.ReadAllText("Test.xml");
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlFile);
var newXDoc = xDoc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Value").ToList().ForEach(e => e.Value = "FILTERED");
```

However, this filters the value you for all objects.

What I'm looking to do is a filter the value for specific objects only, say, where Key equals "Password"

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can:
A: create a list where Key != "Password"
- B: create a list where Key == "Password" and apply your other filter to this list 
- C: combine the two lists and get your result

Comment: Do not use `.ToList().ForEach(...)` every time you do a kitten is killed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var objectValue="Password";
var result= xDoc.Descendants("object").Where(e => e.Element("Key").Value==objectValue);
foreach(var e in result)
{
   e.Element("Value").Value = "FILTERED";
}
```

First filter the objects according to the condition you want to apply and then change the value of the `Value` node as I show above.